# Accessing licensed fonts via Downloadable Fonts API using Font Provider

Tags: android, android-fonts

I'm using Downloadable fonts in my Android app. I am able to use almost all fonts with Font Provider.

However, I can't use some paid fonts like Arial using Font Provider. I bought the license for **Arial font**. I am able to bundle **.ttf**  with my project but I don't want to bundle **.ttf** with my project.

Is there any way to access the licensed font with Font Provider library?

Comment: who is the font provider? do they have app which supports downloadable fonts?

Comment: Hi @ArnavRao,
I am not sure about the app that supports downloadable fonts from font provider.
But I want access Arial font via downloadable API. But it is not listed in Android Studio downloadable API's font list.

Answer (score 0):

You need font provider app in order for downloadable font work or you can provide one and use it.

For google fonts, android play store acts as a font provider. Since android play store is available on all device, downloadable font feature to use google font will work on all devices.

So if you have licensed font and don't have a font provider for it, either you have to create a font provider for the font as a part of your application or use it as bundled font.